# Advanced SortExpression Search appengine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, search

I have a question concerning the SortExpression:
I'd like to sort a list of documents in Ascending order. I'd like to avoid the 0 or negative values, which I'd put them at the end of the list. Is there a way to do it with a sort expression?

Example list:  1 0 4 5 2
Sorted list: 1 2 4 5 0

Any idea?

I'm thinking in something like: sortexpression="MAX_DOUBLE+field_name"

Comment: Are you expecting any particular order for the values <= 0? Are there any constraints on these values (are they all integer, max, min value)?

Comment: Normally they are all 0.